# SQL Server JOIN over two columns where not exist

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have

Table1:

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2   Column3  
----------------------------
Eva           Apple       15
Eva           cat         25
Eva           dog       35
Eva           shoe      45
Bob           Samsung     12
Bob           Samsung     12
Bob           NOKIA       75
...           ...        ...
```

Table 2:

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2   Column3
----------------------------
Eva           Apple       45
Eva           cat         98
Eva           dog         7
Eva           shoe        3
Bob           Samsung     1

...           ...        ...
```

I would like get select where I join two table as not exist in table1 where join is over column2 and column3

```
SELECT  * [dbo].[table1]
FROM    
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  [column2] , [column3]
        FROM    [dbo].[table2]
        WHERE  table1.column2 = table2.column2  and table1.column3 = table2.column3 
        )
```

I would like get result like this:

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2   Column3  
----------------------------
Eva           Apple       45
Eva           cat         98
Eva           dog         7
Eva           shoe        3
Bob           Samsung     1
Bob           Samsung     5
Bob           NOKIA       75
...           ...         ...
```

Thanks for opinions to solve this issue

Comment: Update your question with a smaller data set and show the expected output.  Your expected result set _almost_ looks like a union between the two tables, but but not quite.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP Has updated the question and your deleted answer is correct for the updated question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nevermind, the question has been updated again with different sample data and desired results

Comment: @SqlZim Do you understand this question?  I don't....

Comment: @Luka: Question is not clear. What are you asking for?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not anymore. My initial comment about your answer being correct referred to revision 5: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45505431/5.  I tested the results of your answer against the desired results at that time and found no differences here: http://rextester.com/MNH75760.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    table1.column1,
    table1.column2,
    case 
        when table2.column3 is not null 
        then table2.column3
        else table1.column3
    end as column3

FROM
    table1
    left join table2
        on table1.column2 = table2.column2
```

Comment: Union dipended on 2 column